# Navigation between Screens With List (Flutter)

Tags: list, flutter, android-studio, dart, listview

I have a project that I'm Working on an app with ListView.Builder so it has function generates WidgetCard, and takes information from the list, and every list has its own button and each list's button must go to another screen, I have about 52 WidgetCard so I made a list with parameter (page name) and I passed it to OnPressed so when it pressed it must go to the page but It doesn't work

```
onPressed: () {
                  Get.to(list[index].page);

                },
```

from the list :

```
List(page: 'Taibah()' ),
```

I'm using get package so what I need to write is
Get.to(Page Name()); I tried it before without the list Get.to(Taibah()); it works but with the list function, it doesn't
Is there any way to do it? Not complicated because as I said I have a lot of pages.

Comment: are you trying to change the screen on pressing the button? And do you want to transfer the data to the next page?

Comment: No, I'm trying to use the button to move to another screen, the button is generated by listview.builder and it takes the information from the list and every button must move to specific screen so i made a list with screens names and I implement it to onPressed function but it doesn't work

Comment: Why is `'Taibah()'` a String ?